# String Query cannot be executed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Hye,

I'm working on code where I can transfer the data from Excel and record it in the Access database. The code I've currently, I copied it from a site and changed the value and some statement regarding to my worksheet. But the problem is, I can't run my code but the file that I got from the other website able to run successfully. Could you explain what is the problem in my code. Here is the code:

```
Sub Customer Log()
Dim cn as Object
Dim strQuery as string
Dim custName As String
Dim ordID As String
Dim myDB As String

'Initialize Variables
custName = Sheets("Batch_Report").Range("D4").Value
ordID = Sheets("Batch_Report").Range("D5").Value

'Database Location
myDB = "C:\Users\intern.maxvue\Dekstop\Adhariah (Intern)\Bar Code System\ReviewReport_v1_2015.accdb"
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"    'For *.ACCDB Databases
    .ConnectionString = myDB
    .Open
End With

strQuery = "INSERT INTO CustomerLog ([CUSTOMER NAME], [ORDER ID]) " & _
           "VALUES (""" & custName & """, " & ordID & "); "

cn.Execute strQuery
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I debug and the line reached at `cn.Execute strQuery`, the "run-time error: no value given for one or more required parameters" popped out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you inspected the variables custName, ordId in the debugger? Are there any further column in table CustomerLog that aren't nullable and have no default ?

Comment: @collapsar no other column in the CustomerLog table. Btw, I've found the problem. My ordID contains characters and numbers. So, I just need to add another " sign at the ordID before and after. Without the " sign, it will just return the numbering value. That's why the parameter invalid. Anyway, thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
strQuery = "INSERT INTO CustomerLog ([CUSTOMER NAME], [ORDER ID]) " & _
           "VALUES ('" & custName & "', " & ordID & ")"
```

Comment: I tried to add some quote sign at the ordID because my ordID all in string, not in numbering

strQuery = "INSERT INTO CustomerLog ([CUSTOMER NAME], [ORDER ID]) " & _ 

"VALUES (""" & custName & """, """ & ordID & """);"

btw, thanks for your help.